# Send new type as parameter

Tags: c++, casting, typedef, void-pointers

The following method aimed at converting a pointer to a variable back to the original type.

The method should get 2 parameters: pointer to variable and its type.

```
void myMethod(void *pointer, ? myType)
{ 
    //convert the pointer to its original type
    myType p = *((myType*) pointer);
}
```

usage:

```
int i = 3;
void *pointerToI = &i;

//The type to send to method
typedef decltype(i) myType;
myMethod(pointerToI, ? myType);
```

How should I declare the type of the second parameter?

N.B. The method is virtual.

Comment: Avoid passing around `void *` in C++ if you can. This looks like an XY problem where you are actually trying to perform some form of multiple dispatch. Perhaps you should look into the Visitor Pattern, or the Acyclic Visitor Pattern.

Comment: @YoungJohn, The visitor pattern sounds interesting. Can you please provide an example that solves the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not 100% sure what exactly your issue is, so I cannot provide an example to solve it. You can find examples of the visitor pattern on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern
It is used to perform multiple dispatch in languages that do not have other forms of multiple dispatch. The visitor pattern is likely to require a restructuring of your class hierarchy though.

Comment: @YoungJohn, Thank you. The goal is to make a virtual method to behave as a template method. Does the visitor pattern an appropriate solution?

Comment: I think you should consider whether this is necessary at all. Why not pass a pointer of proper type in first place?

Comment: @user2079303, I would like a virtual method to behave as a template method. The idea is to allow to send a generic type (void pointer) and to convert to back to the original one. Any ideas?

Comment: No, the visitor pattern would be used to dynamically select which behavior to perform for various combinations of types. Templates are used for static polymorphism (at compile time), virtual functions are used for dynamic polymorphism (at run time).

Comment: if all you want is to convert a type, then you should probably use a cast, such as `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @YoungJohn, Can I use it to convert void pointer to its original type? how?

Comment: with `dynamic_cast` you'd have to know the type you wanted to convert your pointer to:
`myType * p = dynamic_cast<myType>(pointer);`
if pointer cannot be cast to myType the resulting p would be a `nullptr`

Comment: I don't think this actually gets you any closer to what you're trying to do though, sorry.

Comment: @YoungJohn, This line is the method implementation. What should be the parameters?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60977/discussion-between-youngjohn-and-user3165438).

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you would want to use a template instead, which is how you normally "pass" types:

```
template <typename T>
T myMethod(void * pointer)
{
    return *(T *)pointer;
}
```

Later:

```
typedef decltype(i) myType;

myType result = myMethod<myType>(pointerToI);
```

---

The only other thing I can think of would be providing a lambda that does whatever conversion is required.  But note that the type can only be present in the lambda; `myMethod` can't have any interaction with the type because it doesn't know what the type is.  For example:

```
void myMethod(void * pointer, std::function<void(void *)> fn)
{
    fn(pointer);
}
```

Called like:

```
myMethod(pointerToI, [] (void * p) { /* do something with p */ });
```

Of course this doesn't really get you to the point where `myMethod` is able to do something intelligent about the type, because `myMethod` cannot be both virtual and a template.  As a result this approach is unlikely to help you.  `myMethod` can't return the converted pointer, for example, because there isn't a return type you can use (at least not one that would be likely to work better than `void *`).

Comment: Thanks, great idea, but the method is virtual. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure you have any options. You could figure out the type using RTTI if you have enabled it, but casting is a compile-time operation; I'm not sure how you could have the method cast the pointer to the correct type when it is not known at compile-time. (Figuring out the type at runtime doesn't really help you cast it unless you already have a method for each type you will ever come across.)

Comment: I have method for each type and would like to avoid it. Can I declare the MyType at compile time and just change it during run-time?

Comment: I have an idea but have to run out for a few hours.  If nobody else beats me to it I'll post when I get back.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass around types as function arguments in C++. 
What you could do, which most closely resembles the solution you propose, is have a hardcoded list of supported types, and the type of conversion that would be used would be identified by some kind of data passed as the second argument (a character, an enum, a string...).

```
    class MyClass{
};
enum class Types {Int,Float,MyClass};
void myMethod(void* ptr, Types type){
  switch(type){
    case Types::Int:
      {
        int val = *((int*) ptr);
        //The rest of the `int` branch goes here
      };
      break;
    case Types::Float:
      {
        float val = *((float*) ptr);
        //...
      };
      break;
    case Types::MyClass:
      {
        MyClass val = *((MyClass*) ptr);
        //...  
      };
      break;

  };
};
```

What would probably be better, though, is if you could formulate your problem at a higher level, and use a different solution more suitable to the mechanisms and tools available to you in C++.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to send to the method the type of a variable, like `typeid(i).name();` that returns the type name of `i` variable. Is it possible to convert this char* to the appropriate enum member?